# Sorting a scorecard by default

Tags: performancepoint, business-intelligence, dashboard-designer-2013

I am using SharePoint Server 2013 and Performance Point Dashboard Designer 2013.

I know that in a Scorecard we can sort values interactively by enabling it in View Settings. But is there any way to make the Scorecard values already sorted in Dashboard Designer so that the user does not require to sort it in the browser?

Comment: We built a custom scorecard system and sorted it using Metadata to filter our views.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can have a scorecard with values sorted by default. For this we need a **Named Set** that sorts out the dimension member in SSAS cube.

Sorting can be done in two ways:

1. Sort by Measure
2. Sort by Dimension Member

Following is the sample code to be included in the **Named Set**. 
[image]

Use the parameter **DESC** if you want to sort in descending other.

Once you have the **Named Set** ready, drag and drop it in your scorecard. The benefit is you still have interactive sorting available in the browser. 
More knowledge about MDX sorting can be acquired from this [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3129/order-and-sort-with-mdx-in-sql-server-analysis-services/).

Happy Sorting. :)